# Convert modified manifest files back to JarEntry

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest.mf

At work we use a lot of third-party libraries that come already signed. Some of them are no longer maintained, but we still need to use them. Due to recent Java security update the manifest files in those jars need to be updated to include extra security attributes. Given how jar files work I need to perform unpack-edit-repack procedure on each jar.

This involves unpacking the jar, adding extra attributes to the manifest while removing already present SHA1 signature strings, repacking and resigning the jar with our own signature. Here's the code I have so far to unpack the jar:

```
public static void unpackJarFile(File srcJarFile) throws IOException{
    File tmpJarFile = File.createTempFile("tempJar", ".tmp");
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(srcJarFile);
    JarOutputStream tempJarOutputStream = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tmpJarFile));

    //Copy original jar file to the temporary one.
    Enumeration<JarEntry> jarEntries = jarFile.entries();
    while(jarEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry temp = jarEntries.nextElement();

        //if file is manifest then unsign else carry on
        JarEntry entry = isManifestFile(temp) ? unsignManifest(temp, jarFile) : temp;
        // ingore files ending in .SF and .RSA
        if (fileIsNotSignature(entry)){
            InputStream entryInputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
            tempJarOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = entryInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                tempJarOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
    tempJarOutputStream.close();
    jarFile.close();
    srcJarFile.delete();
    tmpJarFile.renameTo(srcJarFile);
}

  private static JarEntry unsignManifest(JarEntry signed, JarFile jarFile) throws IOException {

    //extract signed manifest contents into a temp text file
    File tmpManifestFile = File.createTempFile("tempManifest", ".tmp");
    tmpManifestFile.deleteOnExit();
    Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpManifestFile);

    //write out manifest contents to an actual file on disk for later editing
    manifest.write(fos);
    fos.close();

    //read the physical file back in line by line so that SHA1 strings 
    //can be ignored when creating a new manifest file.
    Path path = Paths.get(tmpManifestFile.getPath());
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());

    // some logic here. Something like
    // for each line : lines
    // if !line.contains("SHA1-Digest: SWDa1ic/T+le1N+UvrAYf89lY4E=")
    // write it out to the new manifest file
    // append extra security attributes
    //convert new manifest file to new JarEntry unsigned
    // return JarEntry

    return unsigned;

}
```

Given the one-way nature of Java's JarEntry and Manifest classes it looks like I have to do all the heavy lifting. I'm okay getting the values out, but selectively putting them in is painful in my opinion. So far, I can unpack and repack jars just fine. As you can see at the end of the code I just can't figure out how to selectively put contents back into the manifest file and convert it to JarEntry so that unpackJarFile() method thinks that newly-created manifest file came from the original jar.

Thanks in advance.